# "Duplicate identifier" errors with Angular2 and TSD

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, angular, tsd

I'm trying to convert a project from Angular 1 to Angular 2.

This is a client & server project with some common code (so I keep it together). I want to use Angular 2 on the client side so I followed the [ng2 QuickStart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). I am currently trying to build it inside my project.

I am using `TSD` to manage my dependencies typings. Some of these dependencies like `socket.io` rely on `node.d.ts`.
My problem is that `angular2` already expose `node.d.ts` and create an ambient definition so when I want to use `TSD` with `angular2` I get a conflict between the two definitions :

`typings\node\node.d.ts(961,9): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'path'.`

Here is my gulp task :

```
gulp.task('build.conflict', function(){

  var browserProject = tsc.createProject('browser.tsconfig.json', {
    typescript: typescript
  });

  var src = [
    'src/browser/**/*.ts',
    'typings/**/*.d.ts' // commenting out this line results in unknown modules
  ];

  var result = gulp.src(src)
    .pipe(tsc(browserProject));

  return result.js
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/browser'));

});
```

I also set up [a simple repository](https://github.com/Demurgos/angular2-typings-conflict) demonstrating my issue.
How can I solve this error while still keeping my `TSD` typings. (The best solution would be to prevent `angular2` to expose its internal `node.d.ts`)

Comment: Ok, so I just discovered [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) and was able to set up a quick fix. Once it's more stable I'll post an answer.

Comment: So I assume it never became more stable?

Comment: Still waiting for an official fix. There are some open issues on Angular's Github and TS seems to be working with Typings currently so I hope we'll get a reliable solution soon.

Comment: Quick fix would be cool :)

Answer (score 0):

If you started using Typings, you could only allow discovering `*.d.ts` from browser dependencies in `tsconfig.json`. [Here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-force/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L15) is an excellent example at John Papa's NgConf demo.

UPDATE: This is outdated per Typings > 1.0.0.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about this question. I actually became a typings contributor: actually your answer seems outdated with the new structure since version 1.0.0 -> you should just add the whole typings directory

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the heads up! I added the notice.