# Angular2 and express node.d.ts conflict

Tags: node.js, express, angular, tsd

I am trying to configure an angular2+express project. I understand the cause of the problem, but not the correct solution. Here are the relevant parts of my package.json dependencies:

`"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "tsd": "^0.6.5",
    "typescript": "^1.4.1",
    <...lots of peer dependencies>
  }`

Node 5.2.0 is installed globally. When I run `tsd install`, I get `./typings/node.d.ts` pulled in, for what the comments claim to be v0.12.0 API. But this conflicts with `angular2/typings/node/node.d.ts` (which also claims v0.12.0). The .d.ts files are different, for example:

`./node_modules/angular2/typings/node/node.d.ts
 ---> declare var global: NodeJS.Global;
./typings/node/node.d.ts
 ---> declare var global: any;`

The result is a mass of `TS2300: Duplicate identifier` errors. I can hack around this by manually deleting `./typings/node` and editing `./typings/express/express.d.ts` to have:

`/// <reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/node/node.d.ts" />`

Now everything works, but obviously this is just plain 'wrong'. What is the standard way to pull in expres.d.ts so it plays nice with Angular 2?

Comment: I think this issue may be related https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5807

Comment: Might also be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207110/duplicate-identifier-errors-with-angular2-and-tsd).